# jsonlite not unpacking JSON from Postgres appropriately

Tags: json, r, postgresql, jsonlite

I am pulling data directly from a Postgres database into R, where one of the columns in the Postgres table contains rows of JSON objects.  I am trying to unpack the JSON objects and have them flatten into columns in an R dataframe, but so far, I'm getting mangled results.

Here's my code:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(jsonlite)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host="xxx", dbname="xxx", user="xxx", password="xxx")
query="select column1, column2, json from dummy_table limit 2" 
resultSet <- dbSendQuery(con, query)
rawData<-fetch(resultSet,n=-1)
postgresqlCloseConnection(con)

rawData$json
[1]"{\"id\":{\"publisherName\":\"pub1\",\"visitorId\":\"visitor1\",\"timestamp\":1234},\"startAt\":4567,\"endAt\":8910}"
[2]"{\"id\":{\"publisherName\":\"pub2\",\"visitorId\":\"visitor2\",\"timestamp\":2345},\"startAt\":678,\"endAt\":91011}"

unpacked<-fromJSON(rawData$json, simplifyDataFrame=FALSE)

unpacked
$id
$id$publisherName
[1] "pub1"
$id$visitorId
[1] "visitor1"
$id$timestamp
[1] 1234
$startAt
[1] 4567
$endAt
[1] 8910
```

As you can see, it only unpacked the first JSON object, and it left things quasi-nested (which is fine, but optimally, i would want all the data to live in one level in a dataframe).

I would want the data to look like this:

```
unpacked

id.publisherName     id.visitorId     id.timestamp     startAt       endAt
pub1                 visitor1         1234             4567          8910
pub2                 visitor2         2345             678           91011
```

EDIT: Adding the rawData dataframe:

```
rawData<-structure(list(
  column1 = c("abcd", "efgh"
), 
column2 = structure(c(123, 456), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
json = c("{\"id\":{\"publisherName\":\"pub1\",\"visitorId\":\"visitor1\",\"timestamp\":1234},\"startAt\":4567,\"endAt\":8910}", 
"{\"id\":{\"publisherName\":\"pub2\",\"visitorId\":\"visitor2\",\"timestamp\":2345},\"startAt\":678,\"endAt\":91011}"
))
, .Names = c("column1", "column2", "json"), 
row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Here's what happens with the `paste` function.

```
rawJSON <- paste("[", paste(rawData$json, collapse=","), "]")
rawJSON <- fromJSON(rawJSON, simplifyDataFrame=FALSE)

rawJSON
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[[1]]$id$publisherName
[1] "pub1"

[[1]]$id$visitorId
[1] "visitor1"

[[1]]$id$timestamp
[1] 1234


[[1]]$startAt
[1] 4567

[[1]]$endAt
[1] 8910


[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[[2]]$id$publisherName
[1] "pub2"

[[2]]$id$visitorId
[1] "visitor2"

[[2]]$id$timestamp
[1] 2345


[[2]]$startAt
[1] 678

[[2]]$endAt
[1] 91011
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fromJSON` function assumes that you are feeding it a single complete `json` string. Character vectors will be collapsed into single string. In your case your data contains multiple separate `json` objects. So you either need to convert them all individually:

```
lapply(rawData$json, fromJSON)
```

Or, to get the result that you're after, use `stream_in` to parse them as ndjson.

```
mydata <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(rawData$json))
fromJSON(myjson)
```

See the jsonlite `?stream_in` manual page for more details.

Comment: Thanks -- I've tried using `lapply` and the method you described above, but it doesn't unpack it into a dataframe -- it looks like it's still a list of 2 items, in which is a hierarchy. When I try to coerce the results of fromJSON into a dataframe, I get an error that says 'arguments imply differing number of rows'.  I've tried using `lapply` and `unlist` as well on the results, but get gobeldygook too.

Comment: Did you try the second solution? Could you maybe post some example json data somewhere? That makes it easier to help you.

Comment: I did, but to no avail.  I'll add a sample dataframe above to help us out.

Comment: Based in your example data, the second solution (with `paste`) seems to work? What error do you get when executing http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=TgTZKqjz

Comment: I don't get an error per se when executing you code, but I get the structure described in my post: a list of two items with their own hirearchies.  I figured out the difference in our outcomes -- I have to set `simplifyDataFrame=FALSE` in `fromJSON` as the real data has additional hirearchies that simplifyDataFrame is screwing up.  So, given that I can't just rely on simplifyDataFrame, what can I do?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If you want the output of `fromJSON` to be a data frame (as your question implies), then you need to use `simplifyDataFrame`. If this doesn't work, can you provide a (minimal) example that shows what you are after and what is not working?

Comment: @Jeroen creating a json array `[json1,json2]` is also really key to a substantial speed up here, because you don't have to `lapply`. Really helpful. Just out of curiosity: Is there a way to use stream_in with `RPostgreSQL` ?

Comment: Yes today you can use `stream_in`. I will update the response.